# Exporting SSRS Report to Word Changes Formatting

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that I developed in VS2017. If I run the report in VS2017 and export it to Word (.docx) the report looks the same in VS2017 preview as it does in Word. If I deploy that report to SQL Server 2017 and view that same report through the Report Manager portal (at http://reportserver/Reports/browse/) or in a Windows application using the ReportViewer control, the report looks the same in preview but when it is exported to Word from either of those locations the report formatting is different than when exported from VS2017. More specifically, carriage returns that a leave a blank line between text data within a textbox are not being rendered to show a blank line. There are also some textbox cells within a tablix that are intentionally empty in the report that the user needs to fill in once exported to Word. Those are very hard to get the cursor into using the mouse and when using the keyboard to navigate into them it is pushing the text down into a space where it should not be. Any ideas? What is the difference between the export in VS2017 vs. the ReportViewer?

[image: Removed spacing in textbox]

[image: Pushed down due to editing table cell]

Comment: Have you cheked if your textboxes, that you insert are formatted to output html or text only?

Comment: What property of the Textbox control is this? I didn't know there was an HTML option, but that would potentially explain it eating the whitespace.

Comment: It seems to be a property of the placeholder (not of the textbox). This link might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/format-text-in-a-text-box-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The Markup Type on all of my placeholders is set to None, so I wouldn't expect this to be the issue. I have done a workaround (inserting a white pipe character to hold the space) to fix the issue until the issue is figured out.